# Cannot use try without catch

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

This is `PDOStatement->execute()#1 {main}` and Cannot use try without catch or finally

*My code is*:

```
$f_u_id = $_SESSION['memberID'];
try
  {
    $insert_file_info = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads ('file_id','owner_id') VALUES ($newfilename, $f_u_id)");
    $insert_file_info->execute();
  }catch(PDOException $ee) 
    {
    $error[] = $ee->getMessage();
   }
```

Comment: field should be in without single quote.

Comment: so instead of this: $insert_file_info = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads ('file_id','owner_id') VALUES ($newfilename, $f_u_id)"); I should do this? $insert_file_info = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads (file_id,owner_id) VALUES ($newfilename, $f_u_id)");

Comment: Yes you need to remove quotes from fields because that is column name only not values.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax` How it relates to `try/catch`?

Comment: can you pls help me > error > Fatal error: Cannot use try without catch or finally in C:\wamp\www\anusthana\andro.php on line 55   https://justpaste.it/74cqb        @Dipen

Comment: @vp_arth FYI -> solved the issue, just add catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e-> getMessage();
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove quotes from fields because that is column name only and put quotes in values.

So, Try this query

```
INSERT INTO uploads (file_id,owner_id) VALUES ("+ $newfilename +", "+ $f_u_id +")
```

**Note**: You can [refer this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm) for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Use single ' in values**

INSERT INTO uploads (file_id,owner_id) VALUES ('$newfilename', '$f_u_id')

Comment: INSERT INTO uploads (file_id,owner_id) VALUES ('{$newfilename}', '{$f_u_id}')

Comment: @Raju Dudhrejiya, no difference here, at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$insert_file_info = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads ('file_id','owner_id') VALUES ('"+$newfilename+"', "+$f_u_id+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

- Fields should be unquoted or quoted with ``.
- You should wrap your strings with `''`. Much better - to use placeholders for data.

So here is the code:

```
$insert_file_info = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads (file_id, owner_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert_file_info->execute(array($newfilename, $f_u_id));
```

Comment: strange, code markup doesn't work after bullet list :(

Comment: can you pls help me > error > Fatal error: Cannot use try without catch or finally in C:\wamp\www\anusthana\andro.php on line 55   https://justpaste.it/74cqb        @vp_arth

Comment: You must add catch or finally section as error indicates.

Comment: I am new to PHP, can you pls help me in brief?

Comment: Just remove `try` word then.

Comment: updated code : https://justpaste.it/5lppg  error : https://snag.gy/58mTUC.jpg  can i get help?

Comment: Is not error texts obvious for you? I can just repeat them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182326/discussion-between-rathinam-and-vp-arth).